# What's the pronunciation of the word Goa'uld from SG1?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, pronunciation, goauld

What's the phonetic alphabet (text/pronunciation) of the fictional word Goa'uld from the (TV show)/(fictional universe) Stargate?

It seems to have a interestingly and unusually large amount of distinct sounds, perhaps as many as to be similar to "gah-augh-ouwld".

Comment: Related answer: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/64752/31178 Multiple pronunciations are common in SG.

Comment: It's simple: you learn Hungarian, and then pronounce it as if it were a Hungarian word (ignoring the apostrophe). Wait, what do you mean learning Hungarian isn't simple? I've spoken it since I was 2 years old, it can't be *that* hard...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not a [phonetician](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phonetician)<sup>1</sup>, so this is going to be a very amateurish answer from a phonetics perspective.

Different characters on the show typically used one of two pronunciations<sup>2</sup>:

1. **go-aah-oold**, typically used by the System Lords, Tok'ra, Jaffa, and [*nerds*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6l8MFdTaPE) like Daniel Jackson
2. **goo-ld**, typically used by other military characters, like Jack O'Neill and General Hammond

Just based on *who* typically uses the different pronunciations, I'm inclined to suggest that **go-aah-oold** is the correct one; always trust a people when they use their own name for themselves.

Dan Castellaneta's character, the eponymous ["Citizen Joe"](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Citizen_Joe), also feels quite strongly about the pronunciation:

[Wikipedia user Puellanivis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Goa%27uld#Pronunciation_of_Goa.27uld) suggests the proper [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) rendering as [ˈgoɑ.ʔuːld]:

> I'll readily agree with anyone who says that the common pronunciations of "GOOLD", and "go-OOLD" is mispronouncing the word, but the pronunciation listed in IPA: [ˈgoʊ˘uːld] is not entirely accurate either. From the correct pronunciations that I have heard, the ' in fact stands for a glottal stop, which would make it consistent with Arabic transliterations. (How one would resolve this with the name "Teal'c", you got me, my best guess is that who ever was making up the names, wasn't a linguist.)
>
> From what I hear, the most accurate pronunciation would be: [ˈgoɑ.ʔuːld].

---

<sup>1</sup> Hey, I learned a new word!

<sup>2</sup> With some allowances for regional accents. Jack, for example, is canonically from Illinois<sup>3</sup> and played by [a Minnesotan](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000760/), usually pronounces it **goold**. Compare to General Hammond, canonically a Texan and played by [a Missourian](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0204493), who usually says **gewld**.

<sup>3</sup> ["The Fifth Man"](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/5.04_%22The_Fifth_Man%22_Transcript):

> **O'Neill:** Where're you from, Tyler? Texas
>
> **Lt. Tyler:** Mostly. We moved around a lot. You?
>
> **O'Neill:** Born in Chicago, raised in Minnesota.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Stargate SG-1* Season 5 Episode 4: "The Fifth Man"](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/5.04_%22The_Fifth_Man%22_Transcript)</sub></sup>

Comment: You mean you can't repair phones?

Comment: @Richard On the contrary, [I am an expert at phone repair](http://imagesmtv-a.akamaihd.net/uri/mgid:file:http:shared:mtv.com/news/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/breaking-phone-1418768904.gif)

Comment: Clearly pronunciation 1 is the more correct of the two. Thank you for such a detailed and researched answer.

Comment: I read that as ["Phoenician"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenicia) at first.

Comment: My background is almost the exact reverse of yours: I _am_ a phonetician, but I have never seen the series and have no idea who the Goa’uld actually are. I’ve only ever seen or thought of it as a generically alien-sounding name, and therefore one whose spelling is quite likely to represent its pronunciation quite closely. As such, I have always instincitively pronounced it [ɡoɑˈuld], which is quite close to what Puellanivis gives (only difference is I instinctively stressed the last syllable instead of the first and  used a short [u] instead of a long one).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Interesting perspective of a non-watcher who has never heard it pronounced, especially with the short u in your mind's ear. P.s.- too bad you're not a Phoenician. A Phoenician phonetician would be pretty cool.

Comment: I have watched the show, and, while not a linguist, I did have to learn IPA. I actually hear the accent being on the last syllable, not the first, as @JanusBahsJacquet describes.

Comment: I think "goold" is to "go-ahh-oold" as "noo-cue-lar" is to nuclear. The pronunciation or mispronunciation is an affectation of the characters and seems to reflect certain personality traits. The more "scholarly/scientifically-minded" humans (e.g. Jackson, Carter) are more given to pronounce it correctly, or at least more correctly, separating them from others who consistently and obviously mispronounce it one way or another.

Comment: [ˈgoɑ.ʔuːld]! That's definitely it, though not many people pronounce the glottal stop. From a quick look I only found one example: [Tanith](https://youtu.be/9zSlyvOu5cc?t=45) (S4E4 *Crossroads*, "I am the Goa'uld"). Other clips: [Teal'c](https://youtu.be/vqTbczJFTyI?t=15), [Daniel](https://youtu.be/HapOywSgEpM?t=11)